# Get argument value in SQL query with go-sqlmock

Tags: go, mocking

I'm currently using [go-sqlmock](https://github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock/) to mock my database.

Is there any way to get the values that have been passed to the sql driver when performing a query?. Like the `arg` variable that is been passing as argument here:

```
import (
   "database/sql"
)

func retrieveInfo(){
    // this function returns an initialized instance of type *sql.DB
    DbDriver := initDb()

    query := "my query"
    arg := 3
    rows, err := Db_driver.Query(query, arg)
    // ...
}
```

Then I want to test the function, and I would like to know the value of the variable `arg` while testing. I think it should be possible, since it is passed to the "fake" driver that go-sqlmock creates. My test logic looks like this:

```
import "github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock"

// Inits mock and overwrites the original driver
db, mock, err := sqlmock.New()
Db_driver = db

func TestRetrieveInfo(t *testing.T){
   // query that matchs the one in retrieveInfo()
   query := "..."
   queryRows := sqlmock.NewRows([]string{"column1, column2"}).FromCSVString("value1, value2")
   mock.ExpectQuery(query).WillReturnRows(queryRows)
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for this https://godoc.org/github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock#ExpectedQuery.WithArgs? Or do you want to inspect the arguments yourself? If the latter `sqlmock` does not seem provide an api for that.

Comment: I wanted to inspect them, thought there should be some way, either with sqlmock or not. The documentation on sqlmock is not too extensive, and I wasn't able to find what I wanted, so I though that maybe someone have faced the same problem. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: If you want to inspect the args anyway, you can write your own mock implementation of the db driver.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the real driver with instrumentation to log the values.

Use package [github.com/luna-duclos/instrumentedsql](https://github.com/luna-duclos/instrumentedsql).

Answer (score 0):

You can capture an arg value by making your own Match method, e.g.

```
type ArgCapture struct {
    CapturedValue driver.Value
}

func (a *ArgCapture) Match(value driver.Value) bool {
    a.CapturedValue = value

    return true
}
```

Then in your test you'd have something like

```
capture := &ArgCapture{}
mock.ExpectQuery(query).WithArgs(argCapture).WillReturnRows(queryRows)
```

Then you can do assertions or whatever on `capture.CapturedValue`